# Connecting different wireless AP devices

Tags: networking

Is it possible to connect three different vendor devices (mikrotik 951, Engenius Ens620ext & TP link to Wa901nd) to act as a single wap. 
The mikrotik is the parent device acting as DHCP server. I want the three to broadcast single SSID

Answer (score 0):

If all devices are correctly set up (distribution LAN bridged to WLAN AP, devices connected by LAN), then yes, you can use a single SSID, and it will "just work". You can also use a single device as DHCP server.

And no, it won't be a single AP, it will be three APs, so a client device must still decide with which AP to associate, and it must change the association when someone carries the device around.

And no, you can't do this via WLAN alone.

Comment: I just want to add, - set on all WiFi access points different channels but keep SSID the same. Scan air for less busy channels for example with `WiFi Analyzer` app for android and assign less crowded channels to your APs

Comment: If I scan for wlan, I see same SSID showing thrice on my device. How can I get the APs to show as one SSID.

Comment: You can't get the three devices to show as one SSID. They are three different APs, and your device has decided to show different APs as different APs, even with same SSID. You can write your own program for your device to show APs (or pay someone to do that for you), that's all. However, you *can* use the three devices as a single WLAN network with identical SSID, even if they show up as three devices.

Comment: Good point dirkt. How do I configure them to be a single WLAN network?

Comment: As I described in the answer: Connect them up via LAN, make sure upstream LAN is **bridged** to WLAN AP. Disable everything else, like DHCP. This may have various names in the existing firmware, as every vendor cooks his own soup... and no, I can't configure your routers without seeing them.

Comment: I configured as stated. Other devices were configured as APs and connected to the main router. TP-link router allows for one WLAN network with one ssid but the Engenius was still broadcasting its own ssid(same as parent DHCP router)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment. You want an identical SSID, the Engenius is broadcasting the same SSID as the other routers, but that is still wrong? Or do you mean the IP prefix, not the SSID? If yes, very likely you didn't bridge it (possibly because the firmware can't).  If the latter is the problem, put e.g. [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/engenius/start) on it, then bridge.